# print line + next two lines with awk if next two lines matches

Tags: awk

I have a file that has an entry for a transcript and then the following line(s) are the associated exons. Sometimes this may be one exon and so one subsequent line, sometimes there are 'n' exons and so 'n' subsequent lines like so :

```
1      Cufflinks       transcript      63846957        63847511 
1      Cufflinks       exon    63846957        63847511   
1      Cufflinks       transcript      63851691        63852040       
1      Cufflinks       exon    63851691        63852040 
2      Cufflinks       transcript      8442356 8443964 
2      Cufflinks       exon    8442356 8442368 
2      Cufflinks       exon    8443768 8443964
2      Cufflinks       exon    8444000 8444578
2      Cufflinks       transcript      8258988 8259803 
2      Cufflinks       exon    8258988 8259271 
2      Cufflinks       exon    8259370 8259803
```

I would like to print out the the transcript and associated exon lines only if there are two exons after the transcript. For this example there would only be the last three lines extracted (one transcript line and two exon lines).

How can this be done with awk?

Answer (score 0):

You can save up lines in an array, then print them once you are sure about the number of exons.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
        number_of_exons = 0;
}

END {
        print_if_two_exons();
}

$3 == "transcript" {
        print_if_two_exons();
        transcript = $0;
}

$3 == "exon" {
        exons[number_of_exons++] = $0;
}

function print_if_two_exons() {
        if (transcript && number_of_exons == 2) {
                print transcript;
                for (i = 0; i < number_of_exons; i++) {
                        print exons[i];
                }
        }
        delete exons;
        number_of_exons = 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2      Cufflinks       transcript      8258988 8259803 
2      Cufflinks       exon    8258988 8259271 
2      Cufflinks       exon    8259370 8259803
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you mind explaining the code a little? I'm still trying to teach myself bash/awk.

Comment: I tried to keep the code as readable and self-explanatory as possible, but it depends on your level of experience. Are there any concrete questions you have?

Comment: I think I'm confused as print_if_two_exons() is called twice? Once after END and once when $3==transcript? I also can't quite understand how the number_of_exons gets populated? Sorry, I'm pretty much a beginner.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The thing is, you don't know how many exons there are until you've read _beyond_ them. What lies beyond a block of exons? Either the next transcript line, or the end of the file. So both should trigger a call to `print_if_two_exons`. As for `number_of_exons`, it's being [post-incremented](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Increment-Ops.html) by this statement: `exons[number_of_exons++] = $0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/transcript/ { prt() }
{ buf = buf $0 ORS; ++cnt }
END { prt() }
function prt() {
    if ( cnt == 3 ) {
        printf "%s", buf
    }
    buf = ""
    cnt = 0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2      Cufflinks       transcript      8258988 8259803
2      Cufflinks       exon    8258988 8259271
2      Cufflinks       exon    8259370 8259803
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat awk-script
function set_all(s,t,e) {
  exon=e;tran=t;str=s
}
/transcript/{set_all($0,1,0)}
/exon/{
  if(tran){
    if(exon<2)
      set_all(str"\n"$0,tran,exon+1)
    else
      set_all("",0,0)
  } else        
    set_all("",0,0)
}
END {
  print str 
}

$ awk -f awk-script file
2      Cufflinks       transcript      8258988 8259803 
2      Cufflinks       exon    8258988 8259271 
2      Cufflinks       exon    8259370 8259803
```

Very Straightforward method, and I'll explain it as followed,

- Set variable `exon` and `tran` to record the consecutive show up counts of `exon` and `transcript`, respectively
- Declare a function `set_all` to set the value for `str`, `exon`, and `tran`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PCRE to do this.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/j2Ft95/2/)

In ruby:

```
$ ruby -e 'buf=$<.read
        buf.scan(/.*transcript.*\n+.*exon.*\n.*exon.*\n(?=(?:.*transcript)|\z)/)
           .each { |m| puts m }'
2      Cufflinks       transcript      8258988 8259803 
2      Cufflinks       exon    8258988 8259271 
2      Cufflinks       exon    8259370 8259803
```

Perl:

```
$ perl -0777 -lane 'while (/(.*transcript.*\n+.*exon.*\n+.*exon.*\n+)(?=(?:.*transcript)|\z)/g) {print $1;}' file
```

Similar in Python, GNU grep, etc